# Validate text file (not XML) with XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, flat-file

I need to validate a flat file ( text file ) with an XSD file (schema). I found  to do this for a XML file but not for text file.

Is there any base class to do that ?

The contents of the text file is as follows:

```
Header

SubHeader (many)

Records (many)

Footer
```

Answer (score 2):

An XSD cannot be used to validate an arbitrary text file, only an XML file.

The [validation rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#validation_failures) specified in the [W3C XML Schema Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/) are [**defined**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#c-lsv) against *XML elements and attributes*, not arbitrary text:

> Throughout this specification, **Definition:**  the word **valid** and its
>   derivatives are used to refer to [the following:]
>
> [...] whether ***an element or
>   attribute*** information item satisfies the constraints embodied in the
>   relevant components of an XML Schema

<sub><sup>[Order rearranged and emphasis added from [original source](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#c-lsv).]</sup></sub>

Answer (score 1):

XSD stands for **Xml Schema Definition**. You can only use it to check xml, not arbitrary text.

Your best bet would be to refresh your Regex skills.

Answer (score 0):

May be you want to use Flat File Checker, is an open source application for data validation in import and export files, then This can help you https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43398/Validating-data-with-Flat-File-Checker